# Serialize Collection To JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to return serialized collection from code behind C# to javascript metod and then this javascript method to iterate normal all elements. I did this but the elements are iterated like normal string characters.

```
public string Alerts()
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            IList<string> alerts = new List<string>();

            alerts.Add("1");
            alerts.Add("2");

            string[] arrays = new string[] { "1", "2", "3" };

            return serializer.Serialize(arrays);
        }

<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            alerts('<%= this.Alerts() %>');
        };
    </script>
```

I want the return value when iterates in js to be first index 1 second 2 thrit 3 etc. This here is not working normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're encoding the serializer output:

```
public string Alerts()
```

will return

```
["1","2","3"]
```

When you go

```
alerts('<%= this.Alerts() %>');
```

You're saying

```
alerts('["1","2","3"]');
```

So skip the single quotes and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = function () {
   var arr = <%= this.Alerts() %>;
   for (var i in arr)
       alert(arr[i]); // Iterate over each element in array returned from C# code
   };
</script>
```

Comment: Won't arr be just a string in this case? I think JSON.parse(<%= this.Alerts() %>) should be used.

Comment: @cycaHuH I have tested the code & it was returned as `["1", "2", "3"]` from C# code, which is array in JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

Include jquery and try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function () {
                var arr = <%= this.Alerts() %>;
                var arrList = JSON.parse(arr);
                console.log(arrList);
            };
        </script>
```

Comment: Using eval is bad practice.